# Is there a cleaner way to call multiple toggles & elements during a click event listener with vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple toggles being called at the same time during a click /eventListener and it works but I'm wondering if there is a cleaner way to write the code where it doesn't look so repetitive.

Here is a snippet of the code I'm trying to refactor/clean up. Any help or point in the right direction is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
document.getElementById("menu-toggle").addEventListener("click", mobileMenuToggle);

function mobileMenuToggle() {
    var hideMenu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-container");
        hideMenu.classList.toggle("hide-menu");

    var hideMenuIcon = document.getElementById("menu-toggle");
        hideMenuIcon.classList.toggle("hide-menu-icon");

    var closeMenuIcon = document.getElementById("close-menu-toggle");
        closeMenuIcon.classList.toggle("show-close-icon");

    var closeMenuIcon = document.getElementById("container-bg-toggle");
        closeMenuIcon.classList.toggle("show-icon-bg");
}
```

Comment: I would move your valiables outside the function, to save time searching the dom every time a click event takes place, and use const instead of var. Rather than document....., use hideMenuIcon.addEventListener... I would also add El to the end of the variable names so it is easy to tell they are dom elements. Lots of different things and no exact answer, as there are different style guides.

Comment: @Spangle thank you for the recommendations! Yes, a lot of different ways I'm seeing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few other options

1. To make it more concise, you can get rid of references, which you are not reusing

   ```
   function mobileMenuToggle() {
     document.getElementById("mobile-menu-container").classList.toggle("hide-menu");
     document.getElementById("menu-toggle").classList.toggle("hide-menu-icon");
     document.getElementById("close-menu-toggle").classList.toggle("show-close-icon");
     document.getElementById("container-bg-toggle").classList.toggle("show-icon-bg");
   }
   ```
2. In case if these elements are nested, You can just write a css rule and do one toggle

   ```
   #mobile-menu-container.hide-menu .menu-toggle {
     display:none;
   }

   #mobile-menu-container.hide-menu .close-menu-toggle {
     display:block;
   }
   ```

   And you can just toggle the parent container alone

   ```
    function mobileMenuToggle() {
      document.getElementById("mobile-menu-container").classList.toggle("hide-menu");
    }
   ```
3. In case if you are using jquery, you can use the jquery toggle, which is bit short

   ```
   $('#mobile-menu-container').toggleClass('hide-menu');
   ```

Comment: Thank you! I really like the readability of the first option.

Answer (score 3):

I would write something like this, put all element info in a object, iterate the object and do DOM manipulation. This way a new element-class pair can be added in the object, rest of the code will be untouched

```
function mobileMenuToggle() {
     // Object to store  id-class name pair
      var elements = {"mobile-menu-container" : "hide-menu", 
                        "menu-toggle": "hide-menu-icon", 
                        "close-menu-toggle" : "show-close-icon", 
                        "container-bg-toggle": "show-icon-bg"};
    

    // iterate and toggle class names
    for (var elementId in elements ) {
        var el = document.getElementById(elementId );
        el.classList.toggle(elements[elementId]);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Works great, thank you! A couple of other options also. Let me think about which one I will go with.

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of ways of doing it based on how clean you want and how many repetitive elements are there.

**If you have just few elements, then this should be clean enough.**

```
var menuToggle = document.getElementById("menu-toggle");

function mobileMenuToggle() {
  var hideMenu = document.getElementById("mobile-menu-container");
  var hideMenuIcon = document.getElementById("menu-toggle");
  var closeMenuIcon = document.getElementById("close-menu-toggle");
  var closeMenuBgIcon = document.getElementById("container-bg-toggle");

  hideMenu.classList.toggle("hide-menu");
  hideMenuIcon.classList.toggle("hide-menu-icon");
  closeMenuIcon.classList.toggle("show-close-icon");
  closeMenuBgIcon.classList.toggle("show-icon-bg");
}

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", mobileMenuToggle);
```

**If you have many elements and they need to be dynamic then you can convert it to an array and loop over them.**

```
var menuToggle = document.getElementById("menu-toggle")
var elementList = [
  { id: "mobile-menu-container", className: "hide-menu" },
  { id: "hide-menu", className: "hide-menu-icon" },
  { id: "close-menu-toggle", className: "show-close-icon" },
  { id: "container-bg-toggle", className: "show-icon-bg" }
];

function mobileMenuToggle() {
  elementList.forEach(function (props) {
    var element = document.getElementById(props.id);
    
    element.classList.toggle(props.className);
  });
}

menuToggle.addEventListener("click", mobileMenuToggle);
```

Comment: Thank you! #1 is organized better. I'll keep that in mind for the future!